# Why does one wire cause entire service panel to be hot?

Tags: electrical-panel, grounding

There is one 20 amp breaker with one small black wire connected to it. When flip this breaker on then everything in my service panel is showing to be hot/ live volts. Every wire, neutral, ground... everything in the panel is hot. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Maybe a description of "showing to be hot" would be helpful.  What tools are you using and what is the exact indication that you are interpreting as hot?

Answer (score 5):

A hot-ground fault on that circuit, combined with a faulty Grounding Electrode System, would cause the house's entire grounding system to be energized.

A hot-neutral fault on an ungrounded circuit, combined with bootleg grounds (ground wire fed from the neutral wire) will cause all the "grounds" (not real grounds) to become energized.

Go over the Grounding Electrode System with a fine-tooth comb.  Check your neutral-ground bonds in the first disconnect past the meter. Then check each feeder and circuit for genuine grounding that is in good order.

Maybe think about some GFCIs or AFCIs (most of which have a limited GFCI function capable of detecting this).

Comment: Thank you. I found the thick neutral line that runs from the electrical pole to my weather head was almost completely cut in half. I got the city to come back to my house for the 3rd time and showed them and they repaired it. I'm not having anymore fluctuations in voltage throughout my house and the lights aren't flickering or dimming and brightening like they were. My bigger appliances still aren't working such as my refrigerator, my air unit and furnace, my clothes dryer Could this bad wire have burned up all of my bigger appliances somehow? Is there something I can do or a way to reset any